# "The Calculating Stars" alternate timeline

Tags: the-calculating-stars

I'm reading [*The Calculating Stars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Calculating_Stars) at the moment. The story starts in 1952 with a disaster that completely changes history. But the world's timeline is already different at the start of the book, for no reason I can discern, really.

In the fictitious 1952 timeline, Dewey won the 1948 election over Truman and by March 1952, the USA had 3 orbital launches, beating the Soviet Union. Now, is there supposed to be a correlation between the two? I don't understand the purpose of this alternate history.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  The historical timeline diverged in 1948, creating a background against which the 1952 event can be handled.  *Most* alternate history novels are set in a universe where the divergence from our timeline has _already_ happened, as opposed to observing the difference occur.

Comment: The question is: why make Dewey president? The story isn't about Dewey at all, he's just mentioned at the beginning of the book and never spoken of again.So why make this particular change? SPOILER: he dies with most of the cabinet and congress in the disaster. The new president is a nobody at the bottom of the succession line SPOILER. I can imagine speeding up the US space program was necessary to place the story in 1952, as the book discusses at length the 1950's society.

Comment: You should clarify that in the question.  Given what I know about Truman, I suspect that foreign and domestic policy would have been *much* different under Dewey, which is about the only way to justify that much of an acceleration of the U.S. space program.

Comment: That's the thing, there isn't much discussion of foreign policy. WWII happened the same way, the Korean War is ongoing at the beginning of the story, the Soviet Union is there, China and Taiwan are there, India and Pakistan are there... There's no indication that anything's different, save for the very advanced US space program.

Answer (score 6):

It's not uncommon for alternate histories to have more than one point of divergence.  In this case, no, Dewey's election and the asteroid do not directly correlate (presumably an alteration to history that would cause an asteroid strike on Earth in 1952 would have had to have been millions of years in the past anyway, and as such it's theoretically possible that they're both random consequences of the same event... say, for example, somebody observing the subtly-different heavens saw something that sparked something that made then have a conversation with someone else that eventually lead to Dewey's winning).

However, Dewey's win was important for another reason, as the author writers in her Historical Note at the end of the book:

> Shall we talk about the changes in this timeline? They begin, obviously, before the books start, with the defeat of Truman by Dewey. I did this because I needed a president in office who would be more likely to start the space program a little sooner. This is because I had boxed myself in on timelines with the novelette “The Lady Astronaut of Mars,” to which this is a prequel. I have three other short stories in my “punchcard punk” universe, the first of which, “[We Interrupt This Broadcast](https://maryrobinettekowal.com/journal/45th-birthday-short-story-party-favour/),” is about the asteroid strike. Being short stories, I skimmed the research and didn’t think about the fact that in 1952, we were still five years from getting anything into orbit.
>
> As I began researching the novel, I realized that the technology existed to have launched satellites earlier if I made a couple of very small tweaks in the timeline. For instance, in the real world, when Wernher von Braun and his team were brought to the United States, they were held for a couple of years before being allowed to begin work in rocketry. During that time von Braun wrote Mars: A Technical Novel, in which he proposed a manned mission to Mars.

So, in order to make her timeline work, she needed the space program to be a little more progressed already when the asteroid hit.  Even if Dewey himself died in the second change, his impact accomplishes that goal.

Comment: "his impact;" nice. :)  Seriously, this is pretty much exactly how I imagined it would go.

Comment: @DavidW Ha, pun not consciously intended in that case but I'll take the credit for it anyway!

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen the historical notes. That explains it then.